# How to make mobile apps for different OS

Tags: android, ios, windows, blackberry, nokia

Hi friends i want to know about how to make apps for different OS.For eg: ANDROID,BLACKBERRY,iPhone,Windows Phone and Nokia phone.Which programming language is required for there different OS.Can any same programming language can be use for all this different OS.

Comment: Have a look at Cordova. Its written using HTML5 and javascript and works for all platforms you have mentioned. https://cordova.apache.org/

Comment: you have to try HTML 5

Comment: @SiddhantSingh you should go for java scripting(i.e.,phone gap)

Comment: Too broad, too opinion-based. Off topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To make apps (mobile apps, I think you mean) for different OS's(I think you mean the different OS's on each phone),(assumption: that you're coding it from scratch) you learn a programming language first, then proceed to learn how to make apps for a particular OS. Typically, you purchase a book (look online for good recommendations) and start from there. You can also find tons of online resource about coding basics, and mobile app development.
2. I am sure you can use most popular languages; Java, Python, C++/C#/C, etc...
   Generally, people make either Android Apps, or iOS apps. They code in Java for Android (and it's derivatives), and Objective-C in iOS but Swift is quite new and I heard it has many cool features, and is the better choice to use for iOS in comparison to Objective-C.
3. Yes, you can use the same language across the platforms you listed in your question, but generally stick with the common languages most people use, as the difficulty increases when you choose more elegant languages, like Prolog or Haskell etc. :)

Comment: Also worth noting that there are some pretty awesome SDKs out there for people who want to code once and release on 3 different platforms such as Xarmin.

Answer (score 1):

@SiddhantSingh you should go for java scripting(i.e.,phone gap)

Answer (score 0):

Android and iOS are completely different. You are asking how to begin creating apps for all phones, iOS is specifically referring to apple products. For apple, go to their website and download the development kit, Xcode (It is in objective-c and/or their own language called Swift). For android, it is primarily in java, and some starter development kits are offered for android as well! To make it really simple these are usually used to develop- Xcode for iOS, you can get it from apple; and some of the most common for Android are gradle and app inventor, which you can get from gradle.com or MIT's website respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a good idea which is support to receive good reviews from all platform App users. I suggest you consider about Web App and Hybrid Framework Development. I hope you get a little knowledge about those two things.

The common point between Web App and Hybrid Framework is saving your time, which means a couple of mobile OS can run your App with one-time development. Multi-OS development and different Program languages are absolutely unnecessary for you. I think this new way of development can bring you the concentration on App's essential thing.